# Mechanism of blockchain node switching

Tags: blockchain, high-availability, cryptocurrency

I have a conceptional question about the mechanism of an off-chain application auto switch to another blockchain node when that blockchain node is unavailable.

I am developing an application that needs to query prices from oracle smart contract runs on a blockchain, and I have a list of blockchain providers for me to make the query, to ensure the high availability of my service, my application needs to switch from the node A to node B when node a is unavailable.

There are some oracle providers like ChainLink and Pyth Network, but I can't find any reference about how their node switch mechanism works inside their open-sourced code base.

May I know if there are any examples can refer to? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess,you can use GetBlock RPC node provider for your application to ensure high availability of your service
It can be a good option for devs who need reliable and scalable access to blockchain nodes for their apps.

Comment: That’s what I did!